# Init Generic Class Using Reflection Java

Tags: java, reflection

I am currently automating a process of a data handler. What I mean with automating is that the DataHandlers are initiated automatically via **reflection** based on a specific configuration.

But I am on a point where I do not know how I should solve this problem. It is about this peace of code:

```
Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(d);
Object values = clazz.getMethod("values").invoke(null);
RSA.addDataHandler(clazz,new DataHandlerSetAdapter<>(values));
```

I am loading the class via the classLoader and **invoking a static method** called "values" which returned a bunch of, you have suggested right, values!

Now the problem is with `new DataHandlerSetAdapter<>(values))` which has an error in `<>` because the Object **does not know which clas**s to initiate.

> Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)

Would this code be in C# I would use typeof() but in JAVA there is nothing like this maybe instanceof but I cannot use this at this point. Btw **.values() is returning an Array** of the same type class (enum).

How can I solve this problem?

//edit

with the method `.getReturnType()` on the Method I would get the return type but I cannot apply it to the `DataHandlerSetAdapter<>`

## Class DataHandlerSetAdapter

```
public class DataHandlerSetAdapter<T> implements DataHandler<T> {
    private final Set<T> values = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
    . 
    . 
    .
}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code for `DataHandlerSetAdapter` because this isn't a standard type of error message so we don't know what it means.  If you're asking how to infer the generic types of a class, you can't.

Comment: added above it is just a Generic class

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. But if the loadable class is an enum, then why you are not doing it like this:

```java
Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(d);
Enum<?>[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();
RSA.addDataHandler(clazz, new DataHandlerSetAdapter<>(values));
```

Alternatively you can use raw types:
`RSA.addDataHandler(clazz, new DataHandlerSetAdapter(values))` - note no diamonds `<>`.
But Still I'm not sure weather will this work for you or not. Please provide the following information to understand the root cause of failure.

Signature of `DataHandlerSetAdapter` constructor

Signature of `RSA.addDataHandler(...)` method

More info about `RSA` you used in your code snippet. (e.g. Is it a class or object)